# Alternative Data-Binding library for Objective-C? (like AngularJS)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-binding, angularjs, key-value-observing

Data binding is an awesome abstraction. I use it all the time in AngularJS and it makes apps much simpler. I'm trying to write an iOS app that uses data binding extensively (a game in this case), but KVO is giving me grief. What library implements better data binding for objective-c? Specifically it should:

- Have weak references, so you don't have to override dealloc
- Defer firing bindings: if you set the property multiple times in a function, it fires once
- Defer firing bindings: if you set multiple bound properties in a function, it waits until all are set before firing any (so order doesn't matter)
- Better syntax: don't stick all the observers together (requiring a big if-else)
- Better syntax: use blocks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reactive Cocoa looks amazing: https://github.com/blog/1107-reactivecocoa-for-a-better-world

I haven't tried enough to tell if it satisfies #2 and #3, but I hope so.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/mutech/aka-ios-beacon.

Re (#1), you use it much like XAML or HTML bindings. Binding expressions are defined in Interface Builder using inspectable properties (you can do it in code, but IMHO it defeats much of the purpose of MVVM). So no need to setup or manage KV observations, that's done for you transparently (and reliably).

Beacon extends most views in such a way that bindings know about the target and it's specific needs. You should not need to worry about update frequencies. For complex bindings (f.e. TableView data source), visual updates are typically deferred in such a way that animations are smooth and unnecessary work is avoided. Again, in most if not all cases, this is transparent for you. Not sure if this really answers #2 and #3 though.

Better syntax: You setup bindings by defining bindings expressions in interface builder properties. For example, a simple binding expression for a UILabel text binding could be:

`currentPerson.name`

A more complex binding, also for a label could look like:

`account.amount { numberFormatter: { numberStyle: $enum.CurrencyStyle } }`

A really complex binding for a table view data source smells like so:

```
[
  arrayForFirstSection { headerTitle: "First Section" },
  fetchedResultsForSecondSection { headerTitle: "Second Section" }
] {
  cellMapping: { [ 
    { predicate: <MyModelClass1>, cellIdentifier: "Model1Cell" },
    { predicate: "SELF < $value" { value: 0 }, cellIdentifier: "NegativeNumberCell"}
  ] }
}
```

If that looks scary, please note that this is all you have to do to link up a table view. UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate are implemented by the binding. You can however still provide delegate methods and tune the tableview with nearly no restrictions.

Your view controller just has to provide the (key value coding-compliant) properties you are referencing in your view's binding expressions.